# using cocoa C bridge for for command line tool

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to write a command line tool in C and I would like to use some cocoa functions in my program, but I am finding surprisingly few examples that show me how to bridge between C and objective-c, How do I call a simple cocoa function such as posting a notification or controlling the sound volume? I do not know where to start.

Comment: In a command line app you can get Foundation and access to lots of functions by just including Foundation. Anything more involved than that you might look at http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html or consider making NSApp not a command line tool.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so there's no bridge in place.

Just write an Objective-C program in which you can include as much C code as you like, then use an Objective-C compiler like `clang` including the proper frameworks.

Here's an example

```
clang main.m -framework Foundation -o main
```

assuming that `main.m` contains the `main()`. It includes the `Foundation` framework as you can see.